# Redirecting using JQuery

Tags: html, css

I have this page

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

In this page you will find a button called "get a quote".When I click on this button I want to go to google.com.

To do this, I tried the following code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit").click(function() {
        window.location = "www.google.com/index.php?id=";
    });
});
```

Unfortunately when someone clicks the button, the link appears this form.

```
http://dgprint.dg-site.com/www.google.com/?id=
```

Can anyone tell me why not work? The site is made with Wordpress plugin and used the "Contact form 7"

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
<div class="contact-frm">
        <div class="right">
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="9" title="get a quote"]'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT2:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="get a quote" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." draggable="false" style="visibility: hidden;"></p>
```

Comment: Didn't you post the same question elsewhere? I gave you the right answer there!

Comment: Just add `http://` in front of your address and you're done, else it looks like a relative link...

Comment: @Bartdude Actually he didn't add the part that I added in my answer. Have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/index.php?id=" + $(this).attr("id");
// ------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
    });
});
```

Comment: I put the key and still does not work ... now there happens nothing

Comment: Create a fiddle buddy! What URL is it navigating to, now?

Comment: link remains standard ... do not add anything

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the HTML?

Comment: Okay @Gigi, what about the rendered HTML? What does the browser see? Not wordpress code plz.

Comment: Okay, now it shows. Where exactly does it need to redirect? I mean, what should be the final URL?

Comment: I want to go to http://www.google.ro